# ¿Cómo cambiar el nombre de las filas de un data.frame?

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy intentando editar mi base de datos en Rstudio, pero no recuerdo bien como se realizaba este cambio.

El cambio que quiero realizar es el siguiente, me gustaría cambiar el marco de la base de datos que me sale predefinido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo una columna con fechas y me gustaría plasmar las fechas en el marco que sale predefinido por R.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido pint34 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas es configurar el nombre de las filas, puedes hacerlo mediante la función [`rownames()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colnames.html), imaginemos un `data.frame` como este:

```
df <- data.frame(`Día natural` = c('2021-01-01', '2021-01-02'), check.names = FALSE)
df

  Día natural
1  2021-01-01
2  2021-01-02
```

Ahora aplicamos [`rownames()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colnames.html):

```
rownames(df) <- df$`Día natural`
df

           Día natural
2021-01-01  2021-01-01
2021-01-02  2021-01-02
```

Ten en cuenta que estas usando un nombre sin normalizar, lo que te obliga a usar el "backtick" para encerrar el nombre de la columna.